# Null Check in Jolt while converting string to integer For an Object

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am doing conversion of string to integer/double in my jolt spec. If elements does not come in request, then empty object is coming in response. Instead I do not want to pass that object itself as its empty.

Input Request Working:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "first": "1",
    "second": "2"
  }
}
```

Jolt Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "first": "datas.firstTag",
        "second": "datas.second.secondTag"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "datas": {
        "firstTag": "=toInteger",
        "second": {
          "secondTag": "=toInteger"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

Output if tag is there in request:

```json
{
  "datas" : {
    "firstTag" : 1,
    "second" : {
      "secondTag" : 2
    }
  }
}
```

But when input request is like below where I do not get second tag:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "first": "1"
  }
}
```

Current Output:

```json
{
  "datas" : {
    "firstTag" : 1,
    "second" : { }
  }
}
```

Getting second object as empty

```json
"second" : { }
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "datas" : {
    "firstTag" : 1
  }
}
```

Please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rethink in a dynamical manner by using ampersand placeholders such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { 
        "first": "&1s.&Tag",
        "*": { "@(1,&)": "&2s.&.&Tag" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "firstTag": "=toInteger",
        "*": {
          "*": "=toInteger"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the suffixed integers for those ampersands represents the level to go up to grab the desired value such as **&1** and **&2** stand for **data**, **&** without integer suffixes represent the value from the current level.

**"*"** wildcard represents the rest of the elements, other than **first** in this case(you might have *third*, *fourth* ... as other elements to be formatted like *the second*)

*first case* :
[image]

*second case* :
[image]

**Edit** : For the current case which's mentioned within the edit in order to get

```json
{
  "datas" : {
    "firstTag" : "1",
    "second" : {
      "secondTag" : "2",
      "secondNew" : "3"
    }
  }
}
```

from the input

```json
{
  "data": {
    "first": "1",
    "second": "2",
    "secondNew": "3"
  }
}
```

which had a new entry **"secondNew": "3"**, you'll need to write each key explicitly within the spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "first": "&1s.&Tag",
        "second": "&1s.&.&Tag",
        "secondNew": "&1s.second.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "firstTag": "=toInteger",
        "*": {
          "*": "=toInteger"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to combine the rest of the elements under common object.

Comment: Ozhan  thanks for the quick solution. Do we have any other way to do it without dynamically manner. Because I have few more tags actually which should come only in second object. But if I add any new tags in request which should come in second object, it actually comes as new object instead.
{
  "data": {
    "first": "1",
    "second": "2",
    "secondNew": "3"
  }
}
but needed as 
{
  "datas" : {
    "firstTag" : 1,
    "second" : {
      "secondTag" : 2,
      "secondNew" : 3
    }
  }
}

Comment: Hi @Chethan , you're welcome. I've edited the answer due to your need.

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros Ozhan. Based on your response,i am able to alter my response.